# glGetUniformLocation gives glError: GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm using a somewhat modified version of [this minimal example](http://pastebin.com/2VEasjbu) to get my OpenGL code (in Qt 5.2.0) working with the Oculus HMD. The relevant parts have not been changed by me.

However, the calls to `glGetUniformLocation` in the gl_uniform_2f/4f/1i functions always give the glError `GL_INVALID_VALUE` (it's definitely this call, I used many `glGetError` calls to find it).

I read before that trying to do such an operation in different threads might cause the problem, but I'm not using threads (as far as I know, anyway).

The shader program compiles/links without any problem, so that shouldn't be the issue, either.

So far, nothing I tried helped, and since I'm rather inexperienced regarding shaders, maybe someone can easily see the problem.

edit: after validating the shader program with

```
glValidateProgram(gl_fragment_shader_program);
glGetProgramiv(gl_fragment_shader_program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetProgramiv(gl_fragment_shader_program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
glGetProgramInfoLog(gl_fragment_shader_program, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
qDebug() << &ProgramErrorMessage[0];
```

the result is

```
Validation warning! - Sampler value texture0 has not been set.
Validation successful.
```

and since I read elsewhere that this warning can usually be ignored, I thought nothing of it.

edit2: Ok, I now realize the program has to be validated right before the `glDraw()` call. The warning goes away in this case, but the `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error from the original question remains.

Comment: Since you're using a modified version of that example code, is there any chance you could paste at least a couple of relevant lines of code into your question? In particular, anything that performs a command on your GLSL program object. `GL_INVALID_VALUE` is only generated by this API call when program validation fails.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I added the code used to validate the program (right after successfully linking it) to my question. The relevant code for the shaders was not modified by me; I just de-encapsulated it, so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found out that a function of mine which initializes the GLuint handles of shader programs etc. to 0 is called way after the `QGLWidget::initializeGL()` call. So it wasn't really an openGL issue after all, I just didn't have the correct shader program currently bound.

I hope this helps someone who maybe uses Qt and openGL but is not quite experienced with it so far (like me).